# eror name 'Label1' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

Why doesn't the delete button work?

```
from tkinter import *

def Diagnosis():

    get1 = float(inp.get())
    if get1 % 2 == 0:
        label1 = Label(windows,font = ('IranNastaliq',20),text = 'عدد زوج است',bg = 'aqua')
        label1.pack()
    else:
        label2 = Label(windows,font = ('IranNastaliq',20),text = 'عدد فرد است ',bg = 'aqua')
        label2.pack()
 
def eraser():
    Label1.set('')
    Label2.set('')


windows = Tk()
windows.geometry('500x600')
windows.configure(bg ='aqua')
windows.maxsize(500,600)
windows.minsize(400,500)

inp = Entry(windows,font ='IranNastaliq' )
inp.pack() 
windows.title("icc-aria gui app")   
btn = Button(windows)   
btn.configure(text="تایید",font = ('IranNastaliq',14),command = Diagnosis )    
btn.pack()   
btn1 = Button(text="پاک کن ",font = ('IranNastaliq',14),command = eraser)
btn1.pack()   

windows.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the labels inside a function. When the function ends the variables referencing the labels will be garbage collected. Create the labels in global scope to make the references available.

You have misspelled the references in the `eraser()` function.

To change the contents of a label, use the `.config()` method.

```
from tkinter import *

def Diagnosis():
    get1 = float(inp.get())
    if get1 % 2 == 0:
        label1.config(text='عدد زوج است')
    else:
        label2.config(text='عدد فرد است ')
 
def eraser():
    label1.config(text='')
    label2.config(text='')

windows = Tk()
windows.geometry('500x600')
windows.configure(bg ='aqua')
windows.maxsize(500,600)
windows.minsize(400,500)

inp = Entry(windows,font ='IranNastaliq' )
inp.pack()
windows.title("icc-aria gui app")
btn = Button(windows)
btn.configure(text="تایید",font = ('IranNastaliq',14),command = Diagnosis )
btn.pack()
btn1 = Button(text="پاک کن ",font = ('IranNastaliq',14),command = eraser)
btn1.pack()

# Create labels in the global scope
label1 = Label(windows,font = ('IranNastaliq',20),bg = 'aqua')
label1.pack()
label2 = Label(windows,font = ('IranNastaliq',20),bg = 'aqua')
label2.pack()

windows.mainloop()
```